# Blob detection with opencv

Tags: iphone, xcode, image-processing, opencv, blob

How can we use cvBlobsLib library for extracting blobs in iphone using opencv? I want to use CBlobResult. How can we include cvBlobsLib in our xcode project. I had downloaded cvBlobsLib from http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib but have many errors. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And these errors are? Its kind of hard to help given the amount of information provided.

Comment: missing some header files like #include "cxtypes.h"

Comment: Then the next question is: does this file exist on your computer, and if so, do you have your path set up so that your compiler can find it?